# Delay when using Sign-In via Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have created a Sign-In form in my app which works very good with regard to authenticating users and more.

However, I noticed that once in a while when I try to sign-in I need to click multiple time on the sign-in button and every time that I click I get the following message:

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@f52114e
```

Only like after 10-20 seconds it actually sign me in.

I was wondering if there might be something wrong with the sign-in implementation?

This is the sign-in code:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( SignInActivity.this );
            View toastview = inflater.inflate( R.layout.toast_wrong_input, null );
            Toast toast = new Toast( SignInActivity.this );
            toast.setView( toastview );
            toast.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER, 0, 3 );
            toast.setDuration( Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent( SignInActivity.this, DiscoverActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669921/firebase-authentication-taking-too-long-from-android-device

Comment: im using .onCompleteListener tho

Comment: This does not sound totally abnormal to me.  Sometimes it can take a few moments.  If you think there is a problem, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support